# How do I get to the overpass in The Fridge?

Tags: borderlands-2

I'm currently playing Borderlands 2 and I've reached the fridge. I noticed there's a tunnel behind some netting and a broken overpass above me. [This](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/The_Fridge) is the level I'm referring to.

I don't know how to get to the boxes on the overpass above me. Are they even reachable?

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot or point it out on a map?

Comment: It's the main image on this article: http://www.shacknews.com/article/75805/six-things-i-have-learned-in-borderlands-2

Comment: I don't recall having to go up there for a mission, if you can't find a way up it is probably just for decoration. I have looked around and can't find anything about an easter egg there.

Comment: I see boxes with bright green handles so I thought you could go there for loot.

Answer (score 2):

This area is reachable.

After you pass under the remains of that bridge (walking from the side of Three Horns and Fink's, from a road with derelict cars), there is an entrance on your right. When you first enter the Fridge, the mission takes you left, down the road towards the Highlands, so most people overlook this way. The entrance leads into a series of rooms, one of which opens to the bridge above, and one can leap across to the area you see.

If I recall correctly, these rooms are always accessible. In case I'm mistaken, though, there is a mission that requires one to pass through them, **Swallowed Whole**, that is unlocked after completing the **Rising Action** main mission.

[image: Visual directions]

Comment: Yeah, I was just going to say...keep going through the main mission and you'll get there. NOTE: This is true for most areas that are clearly reachable - they unlock as you go through the main mission.

Comment: How do the stairs lead to the top floor? The ones I see are a dead end.

Comment: @Cocoaster My mistake, there are no stairs. The ones you look at are probably ones *before* the bridge. The entrance is just a door - see picture.

Comment: I haven't been able to get any doors to open either.

Comment: @Cocoaster So are you saying you've found the door I am showing and it's shut? Then, as I said, you need to finish Rising Action main quest, find Scooter, take Swallowed Whole mission, and return to The Fridge.